# Spark Java - Conditional logic for streaming data - Need critique

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a need to conditionally process my data depending on what was received as input. The app is a Spark (2.3.4) structured streaming app reading off a Kafka source (2.3.0). I can successfully read the data, get it in, parse it and so on.

Based on what data the message contains, I need to branch out my further processing. I have a working approach laid out below in the code and need a critical evaluation to see if that is the best way or another better one is available.

Working approach laid out below. Based on the message, I need to do many further transformations and also save various transformed outputs to a DB and finally provide an answer in a csv or json.

```
//raw streaming data from kafka here
Dataset<String> values = dsRawData
                    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                    .as(Encoders.STRING());

//conditional processing check here
Dataset<String> csvIn = values 
                    .map((MapFunction<String, String>) se -> {
                        String[] controls = se.split(",");
                        secoreLog.info(logHeader+"controls: " + controls[0]);

                        if(controls[0].equals("magic1") && controls[1].equals("magic2") &&
                                controls[2].equals("magic2") && controls[3].equals("magic1")){
                            //trigger transformations & writes
                        }
                        else {
                            //trigger a different set of transformations & writes
                        }

                        return controls.toString();
                    }, Encoders.STRING());
```

Please review and give your opinions!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use filters and then have different writeStreams based on your requirement.
I think that would be a better approach.
Also, you will be better able to tackle each Streaming Query appropriately.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok. So, if I understood you correctly, what you are advocating is 2 different filters each coded to recognize the type of message? This then gives me two Datasets, one with type 1 messages and the other with type 2?

Comment: Yes! Use them individually and use `spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination`